# RVM Cant find system versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, raspberry-pi, rvm

I installed rvm on a raspberry pi. 
I am trying to use ruby version 1.9.3.

### rvm list known

#### # MRI Rubies

[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420] 
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head 
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431] 
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330] 
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551] 
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p598] 
[ruby-]2.1.4 
[ruby-]2.1[.5] 
[ruby-]2.2.0 
[ruby-]2.2-head 
ruby-head

### rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p551

ruby-1.9.3-p551 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551'

### ruby -v

ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [armv6l-linux-eabihf]

### sudo ruby -v

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [arm-linux-eabihf]

When I type rvm fix-permissions I get no errors
When I type rvm cleanup all almost every chmod fails

### rvm use system

### rvm info

system:

system: 
    uname:       "Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+ #755 PREEMPT Thu Feb 12 17:14:31 GMT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux" 
    system:      "debian/7/armhf" 
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)" 
    zsh:         " => not installed"

rvm: 
    version:      "rvm 1.26.10 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]" 
    updated:      "16 hours 26 minutes 35 seconds ago" 
    path:         "/usr/local/rvm"

homes:
    gem:          "not set" 
    ruby:         "not set"

binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby" 
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb" 
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem" 
    rake:         ""

environment: 
    PATH:        "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/pi/.rvm/bin" 
    GEM_HOME:     "" 
    GEM_PATH:     "" 
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "" 
    IRBRC:        "" 
    RUBYOPT:      "" 
    gemset:       ""

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not installed Ruby on Raspbian, install it first:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Then tell RVM to use the system Ruby:

```
rvm use system
```

Now run:

```
ruby -v
```

Which should output:

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [arm-linux-eabihf]
```

Comment: Wow, I have been trying to figure that out for so long thank you.